# How to create an extra field in attribute information

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

I am trying to add a field to the attribute information section. This should be an text field for multistore ( just like the manage titles section).

Magento version: 2.2.6

Here's what I got now:

- I created a custom module.
- A plugin: 
  app\code\Custom\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\front.php

```
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Front
{
    /**
     * @param Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesNo
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {

        $form = $subject->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('front_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField(
            'label_field',
            'text',
            [
                "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'name' => 'label_field',
                'label' => __('Label field'),
                'title' => __('label_field'),
                'note' => __('label_field'),
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'translate' => 'label',
                "nullable" => true,
                'system' => 0,
            ]
        );

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

And I also created A upgradeschema to create the field in the catalog_eav_attribute table;

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute'),
            'label_field',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                "nullable" => true,
                'default' => '',
                'comment' => 'label field',
                "system" => 0,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

The field is created in attribute information -> Frontend properties aswell as the column in the db.
Also the value is being saved but I am not able to see it in the backend.
The endgoal is to save the attribute as text ( preffered for multistore ) and show the value in a phtml file. I seem to be stuck at retrieving the data in the  backend.

This is my first time asking a question so if any more / less info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I got it to work.

Override: 'Magento/catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Front.php' to my custom module and added my fields in there.

Also used upgradeschema to create new columns inside the catalog_eav_attribute table.

I think there is a better solution doing this with UI components, but I still need to wrap my head arround that.

Comment: Can you provide your full code please?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: It was solved thank you dear :)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is stuck retrieving the value of the extra field in the product attribute information
i was able to retrieve the data after checking the core files and exactly this file in module-catalog `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Advanced.php` where i found that it retrieves the value using extra key `value` in the field options , here is the code i used to retrieve this value

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\PropertyLocker;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Front{


    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $_coreRegistry
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $_coreRegistry;
    }
    
    
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $attributeObject = $this->getAttributeObject();
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'custom_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Custom Properties'), 'collapsable' => true]
        );

         $fieldset->addField(
            'custom_attribute',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'custom_attribute',
                'label' => __('Custom Attribute'),
                'title' => __('Custom Attribute'),
                'note' => __(''),
                'value' => $attributeObject->getData('custom_attribute'),
                'values' => [
                    [
                        'value' => '' ,
                         'label' => 'Select Custom Attribute'
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => 'value1' ,
                         'label' => 'Value1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => 'value2' ,
                         'label' => 'Value2'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        return $proceed();
    }

    private function getAttributeObject()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('entity_attribute');
    }

}
```

Comment: How could I add component and elementTmpl to such a code? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hey @AboElnouR , i think you want to add custom element that is not available in types 
`addField($elementId, $type, $config) ` where type in my answer is "select" ,
well , you can find all types available in this directory 
`vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element` , where you will find all classes types that can be added instead of select

Comment: I tried `component` and `elementTmpl` but nothing changed.
I added this related question if you could help with it, please. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/358740/81049