# Create custom renderer

Tags: eav-attributes, magento2.4.4, renderer

I need to create a custom attribute renderer using Magento components.

So how can I apply Magento `.js` component and element `.html` template inside the renderer?

Please help.

Comment: Do you want to create product edit form render or frontend PDP? What kind of logic you want to use?

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk please check the following question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/358740/81049
I'm trying to use the product categories component for the attribute.